# Fazer upload de arquivos em servidores diferentes

Tags: php

Tenho um **sistema A** que fica em um **servidor A**. E tenho um outro **sistema B** que fica em outro **servidor B**.

O sistema A precisa enviar arquivos para o sistema B. Claro que se eles estivessem no mesmo servidor eu conseguiria fazer com um `move_upload_file`. Também existiria a possibilidade de criar um link em que o Sistema B acessasse esses arquivos do Sistema A. Porém, o Sistema B não pode ("Não tem que ter") acesso a nada do sistema A.

*Como posso fazer para enviar arquivos em servidores distintos?*

Sei que a pergunta pode parecer ampla, e provavelmente é. Mas o que eu preciso é uma direção. Eu nem imagino como começar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu pensaria em trabalhar com FTP/SFTP. São serviços muito comuns em qualquer server e o PHP oferece total suporte para os mesmos.

Vide as docs abaixo:

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.ftp.php

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.ssh2.php

Boa sorte!

Comment: Cara, uma coisa óbvia. Trabalhar com FTP... Como nunca fiz nenhuma aplicação com isso, não me veio na mente. rsrsrs. Obrigado. Era isso que eu precisava.

Comment: Na verdade, não é tão óbvio assim. FTP server não é *cloud*. Então, não vejo como opção para o problema.

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi, talvez eu não tenha sido claro na minha pergunta. Mas o que eu precisava era enviar aquivos do Sistema A para o Sistema B que estão em servidores diferentes... Por mais que FTP server não seja cloud e mesmo que a tag cloud não deveria ter sido colocada. FTP para o meu problema é a melhor opção. (minha opinião) =)

Comment: @AndreiCoelho, entendi. Então peço que remove a tag `cloud` e também o termo **nuvem** do titulo. Pois realmente me levaram a entender outro cenário. E se alguém com um problema similar, mas usando provedores de nuvem diferentes tiver a mesma duvida, irá mais atrapalhar que ajudar. :)

Comment: Tem rasão @ThiagoLunardi. Vou remover. De qualquer forma eu achei a sua solução muito útil. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa criar um serviço customizado de sincronização. Basta fazer um serviço, que rode independente do **Sistema A** ou **Sistema B** e que fique escutando os repositórios e, sempre que houver alguma mudança, esse serviço então sincroniza os dados.

Crie um Windows Service - recomendo usar TopShelf para isso, veja esse artigo sobre [como criar um Windows Service](http://blog.albertomonteiro.net.br/2016/04/12/criando-windows-service-com-c-de-forma-facil/) - que se conecta nos dois repositórios dos dois providers de nuvem.

Comment: É uma solução interessante. Vou analisá-la

Comment: E se os servidores forem linux? Funciona também?

Comment: Sim, mas para servidores Linux você pode criar uma aplicação com .NET Core ou então NodeJs. Existe um [centro de desenvolvimento NodeJS para Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/) onde vc pode consumir todos os recursos de nuvem usando tecnologias opensource.

Comment: Obrigado pela opção Thiago.